# c# how to make my program run through multiple times without setting the amount

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
class Main
   {
        public string Name()
      {
        string employee = "";

             while (employee == "")
            {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter employee name: ");
                employee = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        return employee;

    }

    public float hoursWorked()
    {
        string yesno = "";
        List<float> hWorked = new List<float>();
        float hours = 0;

        for (int i = 0; yesno == "" || yesno =="Yes"|| yesno== "yes"; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter hours worked: ");
                hours = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (hours > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hours added");
                    hWorked.Add(hours);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid hours");
                }

                Console.Write("Do you want to add more hours? Please state Yes or No: ");
                yesno = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        return hWorked.Sum();

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Main a = new Main();

        string name = a.Name();
        float hWorked = a.hoursWorked();
        string more = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nHours worked: {1}", name, hWorked);

        Console.Write("Add another employee?: ");
        more = Console.ReadLine();

        if (more == "Yes" || more == "yes")
        {
            Main b = new Main();

            string name1 = a.Name();
            float hWorked1 = a.hoursWorked()

            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nHours worked: {1}", name, hWorked1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }
}
```

What i want to do is allow the user to answer Yes or No to the question "Add another employee?:" I can do this by just using the if statement you see at the bottom. How am i able to allow this without presetting the number of times they can add another employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is very rustic. I changed your hoursWorked method just a little do get what you need:

```
public float hoursWorked()
    {
        string yesno = "";
        List<float> hWorked = new List<float>();
        float hours = 0;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter hours worked: ");
                hours = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (hours > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hours added");
                    hWorked.Add(hours);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid hours");
                }

                Console.Write("Do you want to add more hours? Please state Yes or No: ");
                yesno = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        } while (yesno != null && yesno.ToUpper() != "NO");



        return hWorked.Sum();

    }
```

I did not change anything else. You can drastically improve this logic.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I am very new to this so my code is going to be pretty bad :(

Comment: I totally understand and I suggest you go thru a book or video tutorial. I hope that will be much helpful.

Comment: Yeah, i am currently going through a beginners book. I'm just trying to do things it shows me and then add my own thing to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `do`

```
do
{
  input data
} while(some condition to continue)
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/370s1zax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that you're mixing the program flow with the work you're trying to do.  I have done a quick version which shows the program flow being controlled by Main while using an Employee class to encapsulate the name and list of hours worked.

Note that I have also simplified the input by looking for an empty string to determine when they want to stop entering data, but that could easily be changed to use your yes/no responses if required.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Add new employees
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter employee name: ");
            var employeeName = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeeName))
                break;

            var employee = new Employee(employeeName);

            // Add employee hours
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter hours worked: ");
                var inputHours = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputHours))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nHours worked: {1}", employee.Name, employee.HoursWorked.Sum());
                    break;
                }

                var hours = float.Parse(inputHours);

                if (hours > 0)
                {
                    employee.HoursWorked.Add(hours);
                    Console.WriteLine("Hours added");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid hours");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public Employee(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            HoursWorked = new List<float>();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._name; }
        }

        public List<float> HoursWorked { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted but no comment as to why. Note that I wasn't touting this as the ideal solution. I was simply making improvements to the code that was already there as a learning experience.